# How do I deform multiple meshes in the same way?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, workflow

What I would like to do is deform multiple meshes (that are not the same shape) along the same path, or curve, or plane. The best analogy I have is a flag in the breeze made of multiple overlapping pieces, or if you prefer, the goal is to model some flexible electronics.

Anyway if I try a curve modifier, for example, using the same curve on two objects, they distort in different ways. And of course I don't have two objects but like 50 that I want to distort together, which is why I don't just do it by hand.

[image: Stacked Flag]

Comment: The first thing I would check is that your objects are all subdivided appropriately, and enough, to be deformed along the curve. They really shouldn't deform in different ways, unless they are cutting the corners of your curve? Also check that the resolution of the curve is high enough. Maybe give us a look?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume this is your "flag" made of multiple separated objects.
[image]

Add a bezier curve

[image]

Placed it in the middle of your objects group.

[image]
[image]

Select one of your objects

[image]

Go to modifiers and add a Curve modifier.

[image]

Then in the Curve modifier options (Object:), select the Bezier Curve that you previously created

[image]

The object with the modifier will move (that's ok).

[image]

Now, select all of your "flag" object, all except for the one with the modifier.

[image]

Now, this is important, with ALL the other objects still selected, hold down shift and select the one with the modifiers.
Now they all look selected but the last one is highlighted in a diferent lighter color.
Press Ctrl + L and select "Modifiers" from the menu.

[image]

All the objects now have the same modifier and all are following the curve. If the objects are out of the curve like the image.

[image]

Just move all the group of objects to match the center of the curve or at the position that you need and your done. You can now modify the curve to give the wave effect that you want and the objects will follow it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Surface Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html) modifier is perfect for this.

First make a object that will hold the animation. I used an edited grid object and applied a cloth sim to it, added a force field and quickly simulated a flag blowing in the wind.
[image: animated gif of the simulated flag blowing in the wind]

This is the animation. (You could generate this animation any way you like, the cloth sim is just an example.) The important thing here is we have a object animated the way we want.

Now to transfer this animation to the real objects that make your flag, simply add the *Surface Deform* modifier to each object that makes up your flag. Set the *Target* to the object holding the animation added in the first step, and then click the large *Bind* button. You will have to go in and click *Bind* on every object, simply copying the modifier with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Modifiers* will not work, (but gives interesting results).

Here is the animation transferred to all my objects making up my flag. 
[image: animated gif showing the transferred animation data]